# How to replace commas within double quotes in a CSV using Power Automate?

Tags: json, csv, power-automate

I am trying to convert a CSV to JSON in Power Automate. I am stuck because some of my CSV values contain commas within double quotes. I'm splitting each line with

`split(outputs('CurrentTableRow'), ',')`

which of course splits the value between the quotes.

I have not figured out a way of replacing the commas. I've been browsing forums for days...

I need to replace the commas within the double quoted values or prevent the split of values within the double quotes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution to bypass this problem was by decodeBase64() function :

```
replace(body('Json_object')?['Description'],decodeBase64('LA=='), '*$*')
```

the 'LA==' matches to , in Base64

[The box before running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USc2g.png)

[The result after running the flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0oSs.png)

Comment: How does this solve the problem? The poster's issue is that they need to *not* replace commas within "quotes", and preserve commas outside of "quotes".